# HttpRequestMessage doesn't contains HttpClient's DefaultRequestHeaders

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpclient

I have `HttpClient` with a `DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` header. I set this header like in the code snippet below, but it's not present at the `HttpRequestMessage`.

```cs
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {_authInfo.AccessToken}");
```

Then make a `POST` request with this HTTP client and receive a `401 Unauthorized` status code.

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("Tokens/Revoke", content);
```

**UPD:**
To check whether the issue is really with DefaultRequestHeaders, I created a HttpRequestMessage with the required authorization header, but that wasn't helpful.

```cs
using var reqMsg = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5080/Tokens/Revoke"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = content,
    Headers = { {"Authorization", $"Bearer {_authInfo.AccessToken}"} }
};
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(reqMsg, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Then I set a breakpoint at request validation middleware at my backend service to check if the header is present. And unfortunately, it wasn't there. I can't understand how that works. It looks like black magic.

Can somebody please point me where I should dig?

Some screenshots from debugging
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don’t think it will merge those properties

Comment: @DanielA.White, but why? HttpClient's Default headers according to the docs it's a set of headers that will be added to each request processed with the HTTP client.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=winrt-22621

Answer (score 1):

My web.api use bearer token and i had to add this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Authentication:SecretForKey"]))
    };
});
```

Try work with this.

Comment: I have a similar section on my startup on the API side. The most confusing thing is that if I send a request from the Postman it works and I receive 200OK status, but from code I receive 401 ;(


Now I rewrote my code to RestSharp and the headers are included in the request message. But I still receive 401 Unauthrized